# What does this main function calculate the odd integer values?

Tags: c++, if-statement

0x1 is the hex for 1 if i am not wrong, but how is that  `(i & 0x1)` checking if the value is odd?

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> ivec{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

    for (auto i : ivec) {
        cout << ((i & 0x1) ? i * 2 : i) << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i & 1` returns the least significant bit of `i`. If it's set the number is odd. Even numbers: `2 == 0b10`, `4 == 0b100`, `6 == 0b110`, ... odd numbers: `1 == 0b1`, `3 == 0b11`, `5 == 0b101`, `7 == 0b111`, ...

Comment: @ThomasSablik oh!! thanks that cleared it

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the [bitwise AND operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/bitwise-and-operator-amp?view=msvc-160)?

If your familiar with binary numbers and conversions, we know that every power of two (except 2 to the power 0) is an even number. This means that in order for a number to be odd, the first bit (Least Significant Bit, aka LSB) should be 1. So without using the mod (`%`) operator, we can bitwise AND the *value* with `0x1` (which is 1) to check if the *value* has its LSB set to 1. If so its an odd number.

The rest is simple, its a single line `if-else` statement. It works like this,

```
(condition) ? if_true : if_false;
```

So basically if its an odd number, we multiply that value by 2. If its even, we return it.

Comment: _"we know that every power of two"_ it's not only power of two. All multiples of two are even numbers.